# How to get the local file when uploading it to amazon aws s3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

This is the solution I found online: [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/s3-example-photo-album.html]

```
function addPhoto(albumName) {
  var files = document.getElementById('photoupload').files;
  if (!files.length) {
    return console.log('Please choose a file to upload first.');
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var fileName = file.name;
  var albumPhotosKey = encodeURIComponent(albumName) + '//';

  var photoKey = albumPhotosKey + fileName;
  s3.upload({
    Key: photoKey,
    Body: file,
    ACL: 'public-read'
  }, function(err, data) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log('There was an error uploading your photo: ', err.message);
    }
    console.log('Successfully uploaded photo.');
    viewAlbum(albumName);
  });
}
```

However, in my current environment, there is no such concept called "document".  I don't really know how "document" works.  Can I include "document" in my current environment? Or can I use something else to get the local file[an image]?  Thanks a lot!

s3.upload: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify, what your environment is. `document` object makes sense only in HTML, a web page running in the browser. If you're not running in a browser but standalone, you probably use Node.js.

As [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#upload-property) says, the `Body` parameter can be of Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String or ReadableStream.

So a simple upload of a local file in Node.js could look like:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var stream = fs.createReadStream('/my/file');

s3.upload({
   Bucket: 'mybucket',
   Key: 'myfile'
   Body: stream
}, function(err, data) {
   if (err) return console.log('Error by uploading.', err.message);
   console.log('Successfully uploaded.');
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The Document Object Model (DOM) is a cross-platform and language-independent application programming interface that treats an HTML, XHTML, or XML document as a tree structure wherein each node is an object representing a part of the document.

The DOM represents a document with a logical tree. Each branch of the tree ends in a node, and each node contains objects. DOM methods allow programmatic access to the tree; with them one can change the structure, style or content of a document. Nodes can have event handlers attached to them. Once an event is triggered, the event handlers get executed

**SOURCE:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model

This is just the root context used to access the DOM once the page has been loaded into a browser.

An example of seeing the document model load event:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    // - Code to execute when all DOM content is loaded. 
    alert("LOADED!");
});
```